# How to make double lines before and after headings like that?

Tags: css

I've thought about :before and :after, but there are two of both elements[image]

Comment: You can check the styling you see on their document, by using your browser's [dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/).

Comment: It's in figma, not in ready website

Answer (score 2):

You don't need pseudo elements

```css
.box {
  padding:5px 100px;
  display:table;
  margin:auto;
  font-size:40px;
  --g: linear-gradient(90deg,#000 80px,transparent 0 calc(100% - 80px),#000 0);
  background:
    var(--g) 10px 42%,
    var(--g) 0    58%;
  background-size:calc(100% - 10px) 4px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Instagram</div>
```